# in PHP, when should I use static methods vs abstract classes?

Tags: php, abstract-class, static-methods

I'm under the interpretation that if I need to access a method statically, I should make the class abstract only if I'll never need it instantiated. Is that true?

Answer (score 6):

PHP does not have static identifier on classes, so other methods are needed to prevent one from being instantiated.

You can prevent a class from being instantiated by defining it abstract, and it is a cheap way to do so, although that's not the purpose of an abstract class.

Other methods include defining the contructor private

```
private function __construct() {}
```

Or throwing an exception in the contructor if you wish to give a more meaningful message as to why it can't be instantiated.

```
function __construct() { throw new Exception('This is a static class'); }
```

If you also do not want the class subclassed declare the class final.

```
final class foo { }
```

Or in the odd case you want to be able to subclass it, but not allow any of it's children to instantiate declare the constructor final. (Far fetched situation, but for completeness)

```
final private function __construct() {}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unsure of the question.  Static methods are quite different from abstract classes.  Usually you'll make an abstract class if you don't want a class instantiated, but you expect sub-classes to be instantiated.  Using abstract classes can be very helpful to create a partially-implemented class where sub-classes will fill out the rest of the methods to fully implement the class.

A class full of static methods can be declared abstract if you want to prevent usage of the class, but generally I would say that if you mark a class abstract, you should be able to find classes that extend the class.  If I have a class that is full of static methods I *do not* label it as abstract because nobody will subclass it, and it generally adds confusion.  I'd rather it be called a static class, not abstract.

Comment: Definitely; the semantics of abstract vs. having a private constructor are very different, and using the correct one gives a strong hint to anyone reading the code as to how the class is used.